# MySQL query compound statements not returning anticipated results

Tags: mysql, sql

we are trying to build a query that filters out those employees who are identified as `Suspended` or `Inactive` (those value strings appear in our data table in the 'status column').  If an employee has either of those status they appear in an `On Hold` data table, rather than the `Fail` data table.

In the scenario below, 'Jane Doe' did Fail her `Approval` but because she is `Inactive` she should be processed as an `On Hold` and not appear in the `Fail` data table.

We anticipate these results in the `Fail` table when we run the query that follows:

```
Employee ID   FirstName   LastName   Status    Eligibility   Approved
  123456        Jim        James      OK            OK      Not Approved
  777889        Ray        Raymond    OK         Ineligible      OK
```

But instead we see:

```
Employee ID   FirstName   LastName   Status    Eligibility   Approved
  123456        Jim        James      OK            OK      Not Approved
  123412        Jane       Doe        Inactive      OK      Not Approved
  777889        Ray        Raymond    OK        Ineligible       OK
```

Here's the query we run, but the `Inactive` employee continues to appear despite the first compound statement (we do not have any `Suspended` employees in this data run, if that makes a difference).

```
SELECT 
     emp_id, 
     first_name, 
     last_name, 
     status, 
     eligibility, 
     approved
FROM 
     `pass_fail` 
WHERE(
      status <> 'Inactive' 
OR 
      status <> 'Suspended'
) 
AND (
      eligibility ='Ineligible'
OR 
     approved = 'Not Approved')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `in` and `not in`.  According to your logic, the query would be:

```
SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, status, eligibility, approved
FROM pass_fail
WHERE status NOT IN ('Inactive', 'Suspended');
```

Your text does not describe how `eligibility` and `approved` are supposed to be used.  But I speculate:

```
SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, status, eligibility, approved
FROM pass_fail
WHERE status NOT IN ('Inactive', 'Suspended') AND
      (eligibility  = 'Ineligible' OR approved = 'Not Approved');
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  We tested your solution and it works well.  Tom

Answer (score 0):

Change the OR to AND between two status conditions

```
SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, status, eligibility, approved
FROM `pass_fail` 
WHERE status <> 'Inactive' 
  AND status <> 'Suspended'
  AND (eligibility ='Ineligible' OR approved = 'Not Approved')
```